# Combine same logs and add count with regex

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, I want to use a regex to Combine same lines and add counts at the end of line

this is my log text :

```
"000-00-0000" invalid ssn (1)
"111-******" invalid ssn (1)
"000-00-0000" invalid ssn (2)
"55/22/2009" invalid date (1)
"55/22/2009" invalid date (1)
"55/22/2009" invalid date (3)
```

I want to Replace with this

```
"000-00-0000" invalid ssn (3)
"111-******" invalid ssn (1)
"55/22/2009" invalid date (5)
```

I need a regular expression pattern to count matches and get the count of each and sum them

I use the following code before each line added to log

```
string error; // for example error = "000-00-0000" invalid ssn (1)
 if (log_errors.Contains(error)) // log_errors is my whole logs string
 {
 string pat = @"\b(" + error_string + " ([0-9]))" + @"\b";
 Match match = Regex.Match(log_errors, pat , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  if (match.Success)
  {
   // Remove the line and add one to the same that already exist
  } 
 }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

If the only parentheses are around the line count, you could use LINQ and split on those:

```
var newLog = (from log in log_errors
              let s = log.Split('(', ')')
              group s by s[0] into g
              select string.Concat(g.Key, "(", g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x[1])), ")"));
```

This will store what you want in a new string list. (I ran it against your sample data.)

```
"000-00-0000" invalid ssn (3)
"111-******" invalid ssn (1)
"55/22/2009" invalid date (5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can describe line log structure by Regular Expression and parse them line by line:

```
var result = 
  log_errors.Select(line => Regex.Match(line, @"("".*"")(.*)\((\d+)\)").Groups)
            .Select(gc => new 
             {
                Id = gc[1].Value, 
                Text = gc[2].Value,
                Count = int.Parse(gc[3].Value)
             })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Id + x.Text, 
                    (k,v) => string.Format("{0} ({1})", k, v.Select(i => i.Count).Sum()))
            .ToList();
```